# Collapse result of join's two columns into one column

Tags: python, mysql, pivot, mariadb

I'm trying to figure out a time efficient way to collapse two tables, which we commonly join together, into a single table. The tables contain readings, where table A is the table that contains the type of reading it is, and table B contains a FK to table A with the actual reading's value. Both of these tables are about a gb each on our production server.

The two table's schema is a follows

Table A

```
id | fk_id | timestamp | type
 1 |   1   | 1510155021| type A
 2 |   1   | 1510155021| type B
```

Table B

```
id | fk_to_a | value 
1  |   1     | 30.5
2  |   2     | 50.7
```

We commonly execute a join that looks like

```
select * 
from a 
join b
on b.fk_to_a = a.id
order by a.time_stamp desc
```

The key point here is that the join will give us back a bunch of rows, where every n row will have an n+1 "partner" row.

An example result of the join is

```
a.id | a.fk_id | a.timestamp | a.type | b.id | b.fk_to_a | b.reading
  1  |   1     |  1510155021 | type A |   1  |    1      | 30.5
  2  |   1     |  1510155021 | type B |   2  |    2      | 50.7
```

The first row is n, and the second row is n+1. The only thing n and n+1 share in common is their timestamp, which is always identical.

We want to condense these two rows into a single row, where it would be something like

```
c.id | c.fk_id | c.timestamp | c.a_reading | c.b_reading
 1   |    1    |  1510155021 |     30.5    |   50.7
```

I currently have a really, really basic migration script where I'm using python to get the query and store the result of the join, iterating through this join (this takes hours) to find n and n+1 in order to create the "pairs", and then outputting these pairs into a new table via `INSERT` statements.

Here is my for loop that loops through the join, which is where 99% of the time executing this ETL job is spent.

```
#above is the join, database initialization. I'm using pymysql 
combinedList = []
eventList = list(cursor.fetchall())
for idx, row in enumerate(eventList):
    if (idx + 1) < eventLength:
        if eventList[idx][2] == eventList[idx+1][2]:
            insertStatement = 'INSERT INTO c (fk_to_a, timestamp, a_reading, b_reading) VALUES('
            insertStatement += str(eventList[idx][1]) + ',' + str(eventList[idx][2]) + ',' + str(eventList[idx][6]) + ',' + str(eventList[idx+1][6]) + ');'
            combinedList.append(insertStatement)
            del eventList[idx+1]

    else:
       print 'end of the events'
```

I know there's room for improvement with my migration strategy. Has anyone had experience doing something like I'm trying to do?

Thanks for taking the time out of your day to read this.

Comment: Are the timestamps always identical between a "type A" record and its partner "type B" record?

Comment: What associates the matched pairs of rows of `A`?  For example, does `a.fk_id` serve this purpose?  Does `a.timestamp`?

Comment: You may want to look into a pivot query: http://buysql.com/mysql/12-how-to-pivot-tables.html

Comment: @sql_knievel Yup, that's the common element between type A records and type B records. I should of included that. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Follow the [pivot] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining (data from) two separate rows into one is what `JOIN`s are for, whether those rows come from different tables or from the same one.  You can write a relatively straightforward query that produces the rows you want, such as

```
select
  a1.id as id,
  a1.fk_id as fk_id,
  a1.timestamp as timestamp,
  b1.reading as a_reading,
  b2.reading as b_reading
from
  a as a1
  join a as a2 on a1.timestamp = a2.timestamp
  join b as b1 on b1.fk_to_a = a1.id
  join b as b2 on b2.fk_to_a = a2.id
where
  a1.type = 'type A' and a2.type = 'type B'
```

In MySQL, you can then use such a query in conjunction with a `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` statement or an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement (depending on whether the target table already exists) to populate the new table, keeping everything inside the database.  Keeping it in the DB should provide a substantial improvement.

Suitable indices on the original table might help with the query performance.  You will probably find it more efficient to create any needed indexes on the resulting table only after initially populating it.

Comment: Right - and just to emphasize the trick here - we're joining table "a" to itself - basically treating one version of "a" filtered to 'type A' records as a separate table from table "a" filtered to 'type B' records.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't quite give me what I need, but it's really close. There's a lot of duplicate results with this approach. I could provide my output if that'd help.

Comment: @jwerardi, The particular query I present is predicated on your assurance that the pairs of rows of `a` that you want to match up can be associated via the values of their `timestamp` columns.  If that is not correct -- i.e. if there might in some cases be other rows with the same timestamp -- then you'll need to add appropriate criteria on the join of `a1` to `a2`.  Other than that, the only way I see for duplicate results to be produced is duplicate data in one or more of the tables.

Comment: I should rephrase. How would I go about collapsing the two highlighted rows so that they're only one row? [result](https://i.imgur.com/vrXooqz.png)

Comment: Nevermind, applied a little bit of elbow geese and figured out I should use an alias table with a group by timestamp on that alias table. Cool. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger, I'm having a lot of trouble with how long this join takes to run. Every single time I try to run it over a limit of over 2000, my SQL client will crash. With a limit of 2000, it takes ~30 seconds to run. There are a little over 7 million rows Table A and Table B, so a limit of 2000 is pennies to the dollar for what this query needs to do. Do you have any suggestions for indexes or any other ways to improve this query's performance? 

A.id is a primary key, B.id is a primary key. B.fk_to_a is an index as well as a FK to A.id.

Comment: @jwerardi, If you do not have an index on `A.timestamp` then adding one would probably help the performance of the proposed query a lot.

Comment: An index on (timestamp, type) instead might be even a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide some sample code.

What I would try would be a two-step, in-database solution. `CREATE` a staging table, and `INSERT` only your desired final key into that table (leave other fields null), then `UPDATE` that table with one or more queries which have your desired logic. (One query would populate the id=n, the next would populate a different column only when id=n+1. It may be possible to combine the two.)

First, I'd see how fast that is, and next I'd consider creating multiple staging tables in parallel and combining them, perhaps using a stored procedure and temporary tables.

In MySQL, I'd use the MYISAM storage engine for the staging tables, then combine them into the final table.